# How to fix 'Unexpected DMA'?

Tags: android, dma

When I use the android studio's monitor which version is 'Pixel 2 XL API 29', the console continuously prints the error 'gralloc_ranchu: updateHostColorBuffer: Unexpected DMA', and the screen is black. Other apps installed in the monitor are normal and my Android 10's phone is also Ok when I install it with the same app. At the same time, it runs normally when I install the app into Android 9's monitor.

Comment: What you call "monitor" likely is an AVD, Android virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the monitor and reset another one, and it runs normally.